# How to understand where the crash is taking place from xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to xcode and I don't understand how I'm supposed to tell why the app is crashing from this report. When I click "Open in project" it takes me to a place in the code with little information to work on.
[Picture of crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUcmb.png)

```
- (void)didTapOnJobTableView:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer 
locationInView:self.tableViewJobList];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewJobList 
indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
if (indexPath && indexPath.row >= 0 && indexPath.row < 
[self.dispatchTable count]) {
SDMobileAppDelegate *appDelegate = [SDMobileAppDelegate me];
Dispatch *d = [self.dispatchTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
<<<<Last exception backtrace here
if (d != nil && ![d isCancelled]) {
  JobListTableViewCell *cell = (JobListTableViewCell *)
[self.tableViewJobList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  CGPoint tapLocalzied = [recognizer locationInView:cell];
  if (CGRectContainsPoint([cell.labelPrts frame], tapLocalzied)) {
    if ([d.prtsPckQty integerValue] > 0) {
      dispatchForPartsPick = d;
      NSMutableString *partsPickText = [NSMutableString 
stringWithString:@""];
      NSArray *list = [PartsPick getListFromDatabase:self.db 
forDispatch:dispatchForPartsPick];
      for (PartsPick *p in list) {
        NSString *location = @"";
        if (![Utilities isEmpty:p.binLoc]) {
          location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[at %@]", p.binLoc];
        }
        [partsPickText appendFormat:@"%@ %@  %@  %@\r\n", p.qty, 
location, [p.prtNmbr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]], p.dscrptn];
        if (![Utilities isEmpty:p.notes]) {
          [partsPickText appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", p.notes];
        }
        [partsPickText appendString:@"\r\n"];
      }
      [ShowTextViewController show:self request:SEGUE_PARTSPICK_PREVIEW 
header:[NSString stringWithFormat:lStr(@"PARTSPICK_PREVIEW"), 
dispatchForPartsPick.invNmbr] message:@"" defaultText:partsPickText 
editable:NO autoCap:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone delegate:nil];
    } else {
      [Utilities showOkAlertWithTitle:lStr(@"PTA") 
andMessage:lStr(@"PARTSPICK_PREVIEW_NONE") onComplete:nil];
    }
  } else {
    if ([Utilities allowedToGoToJob: d]) {
      appDelegate.selectedDispatch = [NSNumber 
numberWithLong:indexPath.row];
      self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else {
      [Utilities showOkAlertWithTitle:@"Cannot Continue" 
andMessage:@"Cannot select until previous PVR is completed." 
onComplete:nil];
    }
  }
} else {
  [Utilities showOkAlertWithTitle:lStr(@"PTA") 
andMessage:lStr(@"JOB_CANCELLED_CANNOT_SELECT") onComplete:nil];
  }
}
}
```

Here is the code where this the above is used, specifically the gesture recognizer part:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [self refresh];
 XLog(@"Job List View will appear");

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnJobTableView:)];
[self.tableViewJobList addGestureRecognizer:tap];

// startup the ticker
self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
target:self selector:@selector(countdownTimer:) userInfo:nil 
repeats:YES];

SDMobileAppDelegate *appDelegate = [SDMobileAppDelegate me];
NSTimeInterval diff = [[appDelegate.refreshTimer fireDate] 
timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (diff > 60) {
self.buttonForceRefresh.enabled = YES;
self.buttonForceRefresh.titleLabel.enabled = YES;
}

[self setTimeCardStatus];
}
```

Comment: It states that `didTapOnJobTableView` method of `JobListViewController` is where the crash is happening. Did you look whether the method `didTapOnJobTableView` exists in `JobListViewController` or not? That may be the reason. Please let me know

Comment: @KrishnaCA, Does didTapOnJobTableView need to be in the .h file? It's already a method in the .m file.

Comment: It's not necessary to be in .h file. Can you provide more information like adding code in the question?

Comment: I added the method which is pointed to with the last exception backtrace. @KrishnaCA.

Comment: can you add the line where you're calling this from?

Comment: I added where didTapOnJobTableView is being called @KrishnaCA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has lots of information to work with; you just don't know what it means yet. Been there - it's frustrating at times...

See Ray Wenderlich's site and Apple's docs to get started debugging:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

https://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2

"Unrecognized Selector" or "Does not respond to selector" means the object being called doesn't understand or can't find the method you're trying to call.

When that message is related to the user interface or interaction, it often means you forgot to hook up the IBOutlet or IBAction from the UI element to the code, or there's a typo in the names somewhere, or the method you're trying to call doesn't exist (or isn't publicly exposed) in the object being called.

Make sure you've hooked up your elements from interface builder to the code for the class, that the names are consistent, and that the method `didTapOnJobTableView`actually exists in the class `JobListViewController`.